Неправильное отображение выделенного элемента Listbox
Есть вот такой вот листбокс
<ListBox x:Name="SelectGame" Foreground="White" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="#272734" SelectionChanged="SelectGame_SelectionChanged">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Border CornerRadius="7" Width="55" Height="52" Background="#35354C">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Width="48" Height="48"/>
                                </Border>
                                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Segoe UI" Foreground="#D4D4E5" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                        <Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                            <ContentPresenter />
                                        </Border>
                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                                <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#4750D1" />
                                                <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"></Setter>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="#35354C" />
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                </ListBox>

Когда программа запускается, автоматически выделяется первый элемент
SelectGame.SelectedIndex = 0;

Однако, из-за этого почему-то нижний край выделения пропадает совсем. Выглядит это так:

Если перевыбрать элемент, то все становится как и должно быть
Подскажите пожалуйста, из-за чего это и как можно это решить?

Значения по умолчанию задайте border'у. Также замечу, что вы сейчас делаете свой WPF проект не правильно, у вас должно все базироваться на привязках, а не на именах. Условно говоря, это SelectGame.SelectedIndex = 0 у вас должно превратиться в это: <ListBox SelectedIndex = "{Binding SelectedIndex}"> далее public int SelectedIndex {get; set;} (реализация INPC), ну и затем просто меняете значение данного свойства. Аналогично все другое, в проекте не должно быть x:Name для обращения в C# коде (если только это не часть UI логики).
